# FFmpeg, MPEG4 video rotate and Windows

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, rotation, mp4

I have this kind of video recorded in some Samsung Galaxy phone (info from: "ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams filename.mp4")

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=7048499/423000000
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1920
height=1080
coded_width=1920
coded_height=1080
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=0:1
display_aspect_ratio=0:1
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=40
color_range=unknown
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=30/1
avg_frame_rate=211500000/7048499
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=7048499
duration=78.316656
bit_rate=17010472
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=2350
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:rotate=90
TAG:creation_time=2017-12-17T13:42:14.000000Z
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandle
[SIDE_DATA]
side_data_type=Display Matrix
displaymatrix=
00000000:            0       65536           0
00000001:       -65536           0           0
00000002:            0           0  1073741824

rotation=-90
[/SIDE_DATA]
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/48000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=3772416
duration=78.592000
bit_rate=126154
max_bit_rate=128000
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=3684
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:creation_time=2017-12-17T13:42:14.000000Z
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=SoundHandle
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=original_galaxy.mp4
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=78.592000
size=167808936
bit_rate=17081528
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:minor_version=0
TAG:compatible_brands=isom3gp4
TAG:creation_time=2017-12-17T13:42:14.000000Z
[/FORMAT]
```

Since all my media players does not support rotate-knowledge, I have turned the video over again, and at the same time slightly decreased the resolution of command "ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -vf "scale=720:1280,transpose=0,transpose=0" -c:a copy "output.mp4""

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/60
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=720
height=1280
coded_width=720
coded_height=1280
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=0:1
display_aspect_ratio=0:1
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=31
color_range=unknown
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=30/1
avg_frame_rate=30/1
time_base=1/15360
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=1203717
duration=78.366992
bit_rate=2570692
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=2351
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/48000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=3772416
duration=78.592000
bit_rate=126154
max_bit_rate=126154
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=3684
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=SoundHandler
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=from_ffmpeg.mp4
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=78.592000
size=26503544
bit_rate=2697836
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=isomiso2avc1mp41
TAG:encoder=Lavf57.41.100
[/FORMAT]
```

This works very well in VLC, for example. However, Windows Media Player or Samsung TV does not play it. Windows Explorer does not even show a video thumbnail, so the video file is broken by Windows.

Is not FFmpeg able to produce a standard MPEG4 file, or what the hell is this about? I've tried all the alternatives presented, such as "-fflags +genpts", "-fflags genpts", "-movflags faststart", "-movflags +faststart", "pix_fmt=yuv420p" etc. but nothing worked.

The sound I copied directly.

Comment: have you tried something very basic first, like `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2" -c:a copy output.mp4` to eliminate the scaling. also, are you running a current static version of ffmpeg?

Comment: I try it finally and same result :(

FFmpeg is latest available Zaranoe stable (static).